# Laravel Routing to controller actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I've been trying for a while now to get laravel to route to my controller actions.
I'm not sure of the best way to do this in the laravel framework.

How im picturing it in my head is like this.

I have a route setup to link to my controllers actions. so when i type domain.com/Home/Profile
It will call the HomeController's profile action. which will do some processing and display the view on the page. ( like mvc4)

I may be going about this the wrong way but im just trying to avoid making a route for every view. I'm more after the correct method to this problem or whatever laravel devs do as a standard practice because it just feels strange to have a route for every view.

So far this is my code: routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::any('/{controller}/{action?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index') 
{
    $class = $controller.'Controller';
    $controller = new $class()

    return $controller->{$action}();

});
```

HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController 
{
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';


    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('index');
        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('profile');
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer that worked for me. It's Restful Controllers

I registered the controller with this line

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

And changed my controller actions to getProfile()

Comment: if i have parameters? How call a action with parameter?  
Ex:  
```Route::get('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@index');```

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

```
Route::get('home/profile');
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

Comment: could it be that my actions dont return anythign

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me

```js
$api->any('order_manage/{action?}', function ($action = 'index'){
        $app = app();
        $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
        $controller = $app->make($namespace.'\ProjectOrderController');
        return $controller->callAction($action,[request()]);
    });
```